# Копирование файла из ресурсов jar

Tags: java, файлы

Можно ли скопировать файл `src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml`?
Что ни будь типа

```
Files.copy(файл_из_ресурсов.toPath(), new File("D:\\hibernate.cfg.xml").toPath());
```

Собственно, после сборки jar-ника ничего не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя. Но можно скопировать содержимое:

```
public void copyResource() {
    try (InputStream in = getClass()
                            .getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream("hibernate.cfg.xml");
         OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\hibernate.cfg.xml")) {

        int data;
        while ((data = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(data);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто! Почему я до этого не додумался?( Спасибо!

Comment: Почему нельзя? Есть вариант `Files.copy()`, который принимает `InputStream` и `Path`: см. мой ответ. И `getResourceAsStream()` может возвращать `null` - надо это проверять.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, где именно в jar-файле содержится ваш ресурс -- это зависит от того, чем и как вы упаковывали ваш jar-файл. `Eclipse`, например, по умолчанию располагает папку `resources` в корне директории `src` и при сборке копирует ее в `bin`, а при экспорте в `jar` копируется содержимое папки `bin`, таким образом, содержимое папки `resources` доступно там же, откуда загружаются классы, по относительному пути `resources/XXX.XXX`, где `XXX.XXX` -- имя файла. 
В этом случае доступ к файлу можно получить так:

```
getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/file.txt");
```

Вот сниппет, с которым можете поиграться:

```
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;

    public class Ru_So_772259 {

        // Ru_So_772259_Копирование_файла_из_ресурсов_jar
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          try {
            String fileName = "resources/MyFile.txt"; // Должен быть src/resources/MyFile.txt
            InputStream inpStream = Ru_So_772259.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
            if (inpStream == null) throw new FileNotFoundException(fileName + " not found");
            Path target = Paths.get("MyCopy.txt");
            Files.copy(inpStream, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
            Files.copy(target, System.out);         // Просто дублировать на экран, чтоб видно было 
            inpStream.close(); 
            System.out.println("На этот раз повезло!");
          } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Облом: ");
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
          }
        }

    }
```